# How do you determine if AIX 5.3 has perl installed?

Tags: perl, aix

Simply put, how do you determine if AIX 5.3 has perl installed as non-root?

Comment: Entering the command `which perl` should point you to the location of the perl binary, if it's installed and in your path. Otherwise, ask the admin.

Comment: also look for perl under /usr/local/bin

Comment: Yep, in the AIX 4 system I stil have access to, that's where it is installed.

Comment: @SvenW Unfortunately this is one of those situations where root holder is a business manager, not an IT admin *sigh*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
lslpp -l | grep perl
perl -v
```

Comment: Using `lslpp` is the Proper AIX Way to do this, assuming Perl was installed in the Proper AIX Way (using an AIX Package).  `perl -v` will work if perl is on your path, regardless of how it got there :)

Answer (score 4):

You could run this command:

```
find / -name perl -print
```

This would return any path where perl resides.